# Python: How to find similarities between lists then finding second most similar, then third, etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I'm trying to make an availability comparison program, similar to https://doodle.com/ where it:

1) shows the dates most similar (which I've figured out with the code below)

```
dateSet1 = {'31/12/2015', '01/01/2016', '02/01/2016'}
dateSet2 = {'31/12/2015', '01/01/2016', '03/01/2016'}
dateSet3 = {'31/12/2015', '02/01/2016', '04/01/2016'}
dateSet1 & dateSet2 & dateSet3
```

2) if no common date among the lists then show second most common, then third, etc. (This is where I'm not sure what to do) 
How would I go about finding that out? Are there any functions or libraries that already do this?

Comment: please make an attempt before asking, show us the MCVE

Comment: Sounds like you want to feed all the dates into a `Counter` and then check [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)

Comment: How do you define "most similar"? Do you mean show the two sets with the largest intersection? Or do you mean that the average of all dates in each set is closest to the average of all dates in another set? Or do you mean something different??

Comment: I've attempted removing the most common date, in this example the first date, then running the similarity again but of course it doesn't find any similar between the 3 sets.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thank you, I wasn't aware of that - I think that will work perfectly.